# something about mx records

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record

Actually out of sheer curiousity i juz went through MX records and what came out of the search was quite confusing..i wish to know what the things below mean..

```
1   a.mx.mail.yahoo.com   67.195.168.31   2 hrs SMTP Test   Blacklist Check
1   b.mx.mail.yahoo.com   66.196.82.7     2 hrs SMTP Test   Blacklist Check
1   c.mx.mail.yahoo.com   68.142.202.247  2 hrs SMTP Test   Blacklist Check
1   e.mx.mail.yahoo.com   67.195.168.230  2 hrs SMTP Test   Blacklist Check
1   f.mx.mail.yahoo.com   98.137.54.237   2 hrs SMTP Test   Blacklist Check
1   g.mx.mail.yahoo.com   98.137.54.238   2 hrs SMTP Test   Blacklist Check
```

or even get me the link telling me the need to have MX record or even what this is all about... i have tried the previously asked questions and the answers have all bogged me down..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record ???

Answer (score 2):

mx records are dns entries that allow email servers to route emails to the mail servers for the given domain.  they allow you to run email on a server(s) separate from your web, dns, backup, database, and other public servers.  they are independent of the type of mail server used (pop/smtp vs exchange).

in the example provided, you've got your server's name, the public IP address and its TTL value (time to live) as well as the email protocol used.  There are multiple records for failover and redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider reading the [RFC 974](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc974).